# Copy paste files with certain extension from several subfolders in bash

Tags: bash, copy, paste

Sorry for being naive, but I struggle for long time.

I have a directory that looks like this

```
dir 
 |--folder1
 |     |--- subfolder1
 |     |--- ...
 |     |--- subfolder100
 |
 |--folder2 
      |--- subfolder1
      |--- ...
      |--- subfolder100
```

Each folder and subfolder contains among others files with the extension ".fq.gz"

I want to list all these files, and then copy them to my destination folder

```
destination=/path/to/folder/
```

I have tried this but it does not work for me and I have no idea why

```
ls -R | grep "\.fq.gz" | xargs -I {} cp {} "$destination"
```

the error is no such file in the directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to explain what goes wrong is to look what is actually fed into the `xargs`. So,

```
ls -R | grep "\.fq.gz"
```

This will give you a list of files *without* their path, so

```
file1.fq.gz
file2.fq.gz
...
```

and not

```
folder1/subfolder3/file1.fq.gz
folder2/subfolder7/file2.fq.gz
...
```

And that is why it doesn't work.

THE tool for this kind of actions is of course `find`, as in

```
find dir -name '*.fq.gz' -exec cp {} "$destination" \; -print
```

Comment: This would fail if you have a filename containing a newline character. See the answer provided my M.NejatAydin to see how it's done correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this at once with `bash`'s `globstar` option (that requires `bash` version 4.0 or newer), without using any external command:

```
shopt -s globstar
cp **/*.fq.gz "$destination"
```

Comment: The OP said that he wants the files to be copied **and listed**. Adding the `-v` option should solve the requirement, in particular since there is no requirement imposed on how the listing should look like.

Comment: Your command would produce an error message if there is no fq.gz file present. Though a bit risky, I would redirect the stderr of `cp` to the bitbucket, and instead explicitly test for the existence of the destination directory, so that we don't miss the error case of non-existent directory.